# Install applications from Software center on Xenial (16.04) : button shows "installing" but nothing is installed

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, software-center, lxde, chromebook

I have just installed Ububntu 16.04 (xenial) LXDE on a chromebook through crouton.  When I open the "Software" app on the dash, I see the applications. However when I select one and click the "Install" button, it shows "installing" and after a few seconds, it reverts back to "Install".  Nothing seems to get installed.

I used to get a "You do not have the required privileges" message   but after  upgrading gnome-software the message is gone.

Also, when I try to update the server mirror for downloading software in "Software & Updates" , or run "Software Updater" , I get a message: "You do not have the required privileges"

Finally, I am not sure if this is related, but whenever I start LXDE from crouton's chroot, I get a message that "PID ####  did not start".

I will appreciate you help. So far I tried to follow all the advice given for similar questions but nothing helped.

Comment: Please run: "sudo apt update" in a terminal, and try again.

Comment: Xangua, thank you, but nothing changed after I ran that command.

Comment: Oh... one more thing:   "Software" never prompts me to enter a password.   Synaptic never runs from the dash when I click it.  Are all these issues indeed connected?